# Django customize admin page?

Tags: django

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length =255, unique = True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 255, unique = True)
description = models.TextField()
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
def __unicode__(self):
  return "%s" %self.name
```

I have model like above, so on admin page I want field description has tool ckeditor , but I don't know how to use it, so anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install plugin like this https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor. Follow the installation instructions on github

Then in your models.py add:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
```

and change this line:

```
description = models.TextField()
```

to this:

```
description = RichTextField()
```

Finally migrate you app